# View voters of a post

Tags: feature-request

Is there any way in stack overflow to see which users upvoted / downvoted your question / answer / comment? That would be helpful, if you want to ask someone why they downvoted you and ask for suggestions on how to improve.

Comment: Votes on stackoverflow are anonymous.

Comment: [Is there a way to see who voted on your posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12984)

Comment: It wouldn't help.  They're not obliged to answer or justify their reasons to you.

Comment: NO.  It would cause global thermonuclear war.

Comment: NO... it would unleash the 5th horseman of the apocalypse, cause a zombie outbreak and the horrors of horrors - a one direction clone army

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That would be helpful, if you want to ask someone why they downvoted you and ask for suggestions on how to improve.

If someone *wanted* to tell you why they down-voted you, they could leave a comment. The down-vote privilege is gained *after* the comment privilege.

What your suggested would lead to is either:

- masses of comments on posts by people who down-vote *not about the post* with users asking why their questions / answers were down-voted.
- possible revenge-down-voting.
- no noticeable improvement for *new* users who can't comment on other posts to ask why they were down-voted, except "Here's a list of the people that don't like your post."

The first two are sort of guarded against in many cases by the crap often coming from new users.

I think for new users the anonymity of votes is better. It can mean "oh, twenty random internet people down-voted *my post*" rather than "oh, these twenty people who I can now see and have names and faces down-voted *me*".